# Will upgrading to Server 2008 R2 increase performance?

Tags: wcf, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

We are deploying two server-based applications, one WCF, and one a Winform that processes a lot of network traffic (like a custom-made WCF).

Generally speaking, would upgrading from Server 2008 to Server 2008 R2 / IIS 7.5 offer these apps potential significant performance benefits?

I'm particularly interested, as I've heard great things about Windows 7 as compared to Vista, and wondering if we can expect similar benefits with Server 2008 R2 vs Server 2008.  I.e. perhaps better memory handling, etc.

As an added note, I've heard the RTM for Server 2008 R2 will be available on MSDN within about a week, and that Windows 7 RTM will be available on MSDN today.

Comment: +1 I was actually thinking about this very question today, specifically in terms of speed vista < windows 7 so 2k8 < 2k8 R2?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server 2008 R2 has numerous improvements including most of those that were made to Win7.

However, whether or not you'll see any perf improvement is highly dependent on your app and how it works. The only way to tell if you'll get better perf is to measure the perf on your existing setup and then measure your perf on the new setup.

Any other speculation is just that - speculation - and may not have any bearing on reality!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a performance boost on your WCF services, one of the things that you should look at is which wcf binding you are using and how it is configured.

Have a look at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310550.aspx